# iOS SDK 4.0 & 4.1 add images to simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ios-simulator

I've seen many questions asked about how to add images to the simulator and have seen two answers:

- Click and hold to save in Mobile Safari on the phone
- Add the files to the 100Apple (or whatever) folder

Both worked great in everything previous to iOS SDK 4.0. Those same methods no longer work for me, and neither for anyone else that I have seen. I have tried to write an image to the photo library manually using the following chunk of code I found somewhere:

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
    UIAlertView *alert;

    if (error) // Unable to save the image 
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                       message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album." 
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    else // All is well
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" 
                                       message:@"Image saved to Photo Album." 
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

But it errors every time. So is it a problem with the write access of the simulator? or just some bug? I have already updated to the iOS 4.1 SDK in hopes of it being fixed, but it isn't.

Comment: The Safari method works for me.

Comment: How exactly? You use the click and hold on an image in the 4.0 SDK and choose Save and it then shows up in a UIImagePickerController for Photo Library?

Comment: Doesn't matter, the problem has been fixed by Apple.

Comment: If it's any consolation, you're not the only one having problems with OS4 programming. I'm just trying to learn the language myself (I've done object-oriented programming before, but not for iPhone) and would you believe that Apple's own 'Hello World' tutorial crashes too? I've checked and re-checked it, no errors. No idea what's going wrong with it as I'm new to all platform-specific commands and libraries.

-Ash

Comment: If it's any consolation, you're not the only one having problems with OS4 programming. I'm just trying to learn the language myself (I've done object-oriented programming before, but not for iPhone) and would you believe that Apple's own 'Hello World' tutorial crashes too? I've checked and re-checked it, no errors. No idea what's going wrong with it as I'm new to all platform-specific commands and libraries.

-Ash

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am using Xcode 3.2.4 with SDK 3.2, 4.0.1 and 4.1. The following steps worked for me:
1. Launch simulator
2. Drag an image from Finder to the simulator which will always launch Safari to show the image
3. CLICK and HOLD that click for a couple of seconds, then you will see a popup with a "Save Image" button

Comment: Somehow it has started working, I guess they fixed it. Your method works, as well as just browsing to an image in Safari and click+holding to save it. Thanks.

Comment: Another thing you may need to do is to terminate the Photos app if it's running.  I've done the click-hold-save a number of times, but it only seems to refresh on my 4.x simulator when I double-tap the home button and kill running apps.  Something isn't auto-refreshing until you restart one of the apps.  And I believe it's the Photos app, and this problem only happens for me when it's the first image I'm adding (subsequent adds refresh right away).  If you're having trouble with this on SDK 4, try this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running iOS Simulator 4.3
Using user44990 answer above fixed the problem for me and subsequently browsing in Safari and hold-click to save an image worked for me.
I suspect the first step creates the proper directory:
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
which enable the click and hold method to work.

Answer (score 1):

This question is spot-on.  All the current advice I've seen about dragging/dropping to Safari, creating DCIM\100APPLE, etc, are all ineffective in SDK 4.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy in Xcode 4.2 under OSX 10.6.8 :

1- Drag and drop any picture into the iphone simulator
2- when the picture shows up, RMC (RightMouseClick) and choose "Save Image"
3- back to the simulator´s desktop, choose "Photos" app and your picture/s will be there.